# Plotting with hbar Griffiths 2nd edition quantum mechanics problem 10.1

Tags: physics, units

I'm trying to plot the evolution of Psi from Problem 10.1 in Griffiths 2nd edition quantum mechanics. However, I'm having difficulty plotting because of the hbar in both numerator and denominator (so I can't rescale and animate using t/hbar if it were a simpler E/t wave function.

Does someone know how to recale to account for hbar?

[image]

Psi_1 for example won't plot (only if I remove hbar from E and from denominator of the exponential):
[image]

Comment: Post your code (in Raw InputForm) rather than pictures of code. No one wants to manually enter all of your code so that we can work with it, and the effort would be highly error-prone.

Comment: Sorry about that Bob, first time posting Wolram code, here is the cloud notebook, thanks! https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/004b1615-a5d2-4b7c-bba3-65641d9340f1

Comment: @SOUser Even better would be for you to please post your code as text within your question, to make it self-contained.

Comment: Use [atomic units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartree_atomic_units) in which $\hbar=m_e=e=4\pi\varepsilon_0=1$. In this system of units, the unit of energy is [Hartree](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Constants/energy.html)=27.2114 eV, and the [atomic unit of time](https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/Value?aut) is 0.0242 fs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed some code issues/typos. Use `SetDelayed (:=)` to avoid inadvertently using variables that have already been set. Also, make sure all constants are defined.

This makes plots:

```
VELOCITY = 1;
PSIINDEX = 1;
INITIALWIDTH = 1;
TIMELAPSE = 1;
MASS = 1;
\[HBar] = 6.626 10^-34/(2 Pi);

w[a_, v_, t_] := a + v*t;
energy[n_, a_, m_] := 
 Refine[(\[Pi]^2 n^2 \[HBar]^2)/(2 m a^2), Element[n, Integers]]
alpha[m_, v_, a_] := ((m v a)/(2 \[Pi]^2 \[HBar]))
c[n_, m_, v_, a_] := Refine[2/\[Pi] Integrate[
    E^(- I alpha[m, v, a] z^2) Sin[n z] Sin[z], {z, Pi, 0}], Element[n, Integers]]
p[x_, t_, n_] := 
 Sqrt[2/w[INITIALWIDTH, VELOCITY, t]] Sin[n \[Pi] x/w[INITIALWIDTH, VELOCITY, t]] Exp[-I (MASS VELOCITY x^2 - 2 energy[n, INITIALWIDTH, MASS] INITIALWIDTH t)/(2 \[HBar] w[INITIALWIDTH, VELOCITY, t])]

Manipulate[
 Plot[{p[x, t, PSIINDEX]*Conjugate[p[x, t, PSIINDEX]], 
   Re[p[x, t, PSIINDEX]], Im[p[x, t, PSIINDEX]]}, {x, 0, 
   w[INITIALWIDTH, VELOCITY, t]}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Black, Thickness[.005]}, {Green, 
     Thickness[.005]}, {Red, Thickness[.005]}}, 
  PlotRange -> Automatic], {t, 0, TIMELAPSE, Appearance -> "Open"}]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for feedback about := but this just removes the entire Exp[] with i and hbar to get it to plot, so it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: My bad, it was a copying mistake. h-bar was merely undefined in your code. You can tell by the blue color (along with lower case e, btw). I will update the answer.

Comment: Oh my gosh, I thought it was internally defined when using the symbol. I see it works now!